# How to publish generated tiles to web?

Tags: web-mapping, tiles, gdal2tiles

For example I have some large TIFF file, then I build tiles from it using `gdal2tiles`, then I need to share this tiles with my colleagues.

One of the options is to comress tiles to .zip archive and send it to colleagues, for example [here is solution](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2008/03/generating-map-tiles-with-gdal2tiles.html) how to view tiles in Google Earth, but I need solution without any additional software on client side, so just browser without plugins allowed.

So my question is there any free service where I can publish my maps? If not, I assume I need to rollout some kind of server on cloud patform by myself, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

When you run gdal2tiles command, three extra (html) files along with an xml file are created. These html files are sufficient to view these tiles in browser of system connected to internet. These files are: 
a) googlemaps.html 
b) openlayers.html 
c) leaflet.html

The folder structure looks like the below:

[image]

You just need to copy the javascript library of the above mentioned files (openlayers or leaflet) from internet **IFF you want to view these tiles offline**.

You can zip the full folder and use it on any system connected to internet if you don't want to copy javascript library.

Comment: What if I put this files and tiles on server(do I need ftp or something?) what will be link to map <path_on_server>/googlemaps.html? Also seems this way is too slow and not suitable for large maps, I get error `to much recursion` while openning googlemaps.html.

Comment: You can zip this folder and transfer through FTP or direct upload to your server location and extract there. You are right the link will be <path_on_server>/<folder_name>/googlemaps.html if you have extracted it in your root directory. This method is considered to be the fastest and is known as WMTS. Please use openlayers or leaflet libraries as googlemaps will have issues with API Key.

Comment: On maptiler site thay also suggest this option http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/own-hosting/

Comment: Also I have trie maptiler and their generated `googlemaps.html` don't produce such error.